# tools or techniques to help avoid mistakes in python/django

Tags: python, django, debugging, static-analysis

What tools or techniques can help avoid bugs, especially silly mistakes such as typos, coding in Python and Django?

I know unit-testing every line of code is the "proper" way, but are there any shortcuts?

I know of pylint, but unfortunately it doesn't check Django ORM named parameters, where a typo can go unnoticed. Is there any tool that can handle this kind of bugs?

A colleague thought of an idea to gather smart statistics on tokens (for example about named parameters to functions...), and when a once-in-a-code-base token is encountered it is warned as possible typo.
Do you know of any tool that does something similar?

Comment: shortcuts to skip proper unit-testing... sigh. this is the sign of the times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't know if I understand you correctly,

But I think a **good** IDE has automatic code validation and some of them also work with Django. For example, there is a good python plugin for [Eclipse called **PYDEV**](http://pydev.org/). There is also a good IDE based on Eclipse/Pydev called [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/) that you can try (it also has good support for editing HTML/JS/CSS).

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) is also a very good comparison of all the Python IDE's.

Comment: Alternatively, Pycharm has pretty decent Django support if you set it up correctly.

Comment: I agree on PyCharm - it's not FOSS, but it is really good. I've found it far nicer than pydev.

Comment: Look at this post too for some good suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python

Answer (score 2):

[pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) is a static analyser that will find undeclared variables (e.g. typos) and the like. plenty of editors have plugins that run pyflakes on the fly or on save. This is not a substitute for unit tests, but it can save a few unnecessary save-reload-run cycles

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I'll check these tools.

I wanted to share with you other ideas (none python/django specific):

1. Assert conditions in code - but remove from production code.
2. Run periodic checks on the data (eg. sending email to dev when found unexpected state) - in case a bug slips by it may be detected faster, before more data is corrupt (but alas after some of it is already corrupt).
3. Make a single bottom-line test (perhaps simulating user input),  that covers most of the program. It may catch exceptions and asserts and is may be easier to maintain than many tests.